# C# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when file definitely exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, system.io.file

I'm trying to return a file from an action in ASP.NET Core:

```
public IActionResult GetFile(string filePath) {
    return File("/home/me/file.png", "application/octet-stream");
}
```

However, I get a

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

in my browser window:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: /home/me/file.png
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.VirtualFileResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, VirtualFileResult result)

I've tried checking if the file exists using `System.IO.File.Exists` and looking for it in `Directory.GetFiles`, which both say the file does exist. I've also tried changing the media type to `image/png`, but that doesn't help anything.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: wrap the above line in a try-catch, then put a breakpoint in the catch. I'd try that...

Comment: You need to use a full path to get the file.  I would put that path in a setting.

Comment: Also I would read the file as a byte array and pass that to the result

Comment: The file is in server or in client machine?

Comment: @MarioVernari I tried that but it never got caught

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew it's on the server

Comment: @Darkonekt Isn't `/home/me/file.png` a full path?

Comment: @Merlin04 where the error is generated, then? I think you're misinterprenting something...

Comment: @MarioVernari When I go to `localhost:5001/Page/GetFile?fileName=test` in my web browser, I see this error ("An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request...")

Comment: @Merlin04 ahh! that's not a file-not-found problem, then!

Comment: @MarioVernari What is it then? I've edited my question to add more of the error message.

Comment: `/home/me/file.png` is relative to the root of the current drive. So you're likely hitting `C:\home\me\file.png` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Merlin04 no it is not.  It is a relative path.

Comment: @Merlin04 `File` method in controller uses "virtual path" which is not the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I use in an application, and it works perfectly:

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("download")]
   public async Task<iactionresult> Download([FromQuery] string file) {
       var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
       var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, file);
       if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
           return NotFound();

       var memory = new MemoryStream();
       using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
       {
           await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
       }
       memory.Position = 0;

       return File(memory, GetContentType(filePath), file);
   }
```

This snippet is from [here](https://www.blexin.com/en-US/Article/Blog/Uploading-and-Downloading-files-with-Angular-and-AspNet-Core-22): my code is slightly different.

Comment: This worked perfectly, however I did have to copy over the GetContentType method from the link in addition to the code from your answer.