# .NET Core cannot find Excel file right after copying it

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I get `FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: D:\myNETproject\wwwroot\Destination\myFile20220829160000.xlsx` after running the following code:

```
public FileResult? copyFileAndServeToClient() {
    var _hostingEnvironment = new IWebHostEnvironment;
    string templateDir = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Source";
    string targetDir = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\Destination";
    string DateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    templateName = "myTemplate.xlsx";
    targetName = "myFile" + DateTimeStamp + ".xlsx";

    string templatePath = Path.Combine(templateDir, templateName);
    string targetPath = Path.Combine(targetDir, targetName);

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(templatePath))
    {
        System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, targetPath, true);
    
        return File(targetPath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The file `D:\myNETproject\wwwroot\Source\myTemplate.xlsx` exists on my drive.
Additionally, I confirmed that the file `D:\myNETproject\wwwroot\Destination\myFile20220829160000.xlsx` exists on my drive after running this code. I can paste that path into Windows Explorer and it opens the Excel file. To me it seems like the `File.Copy` command runs, and then the `return File()` runs before the file has finished copying, but I thought `File.Copy` is synchronous.

**How can I ensure .NET is able to serve the file right after copying it?**

Comment: You need to explain impersonation/permissions story for your code/site.

Comment: what is this code doing: `File(targetPath, "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")` It looks like a constructor for the File class ... but I thought that System.IO.File was a static class... ?

Comment: @topsail I think that's a controller method for returning a FileContentResult in an MVC application, though I could be mistaken.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: I see. Different namespace. One other thing that is curious: your time format is yyyyMMddhhmmss but the file name in the error message does not match up with that format. It appears to be either only a single digit minute or single digit second - either way, a character is missing. hhmmss should be `040000` and your file name ends with `04000` (btw HH is probably better than hh in this situation but that's just an aside - 24 hour clock vs 12 hour clock).

Comment: @topsail Thanks for catching that, and the time format suggestion. I've updated the post to fix the typo and changed `hh` to `HH`. My error still remains, however.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization package to implement authentication for most pages of my site, including the one in which the code above runs. However, I am signed into the site when I run it, and this should give me permission to view any pages and files, as I am an Admin user.

Comment: @elmer007 You are correct.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue from the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58759818/6111540 And I have voted to close as a duplicate.